# XUnit TestResult in Jenkins doesnt show Testnames

Tags: jenkins, xunit

Here is the Test Result Jenkins shows me. The names are empty.

[image]

But in the XML, that was generated and loaded in the Post Build from Jenkins, the test names are shown and correct:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assemblies>
  <assembly name="xyz" environment="32-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000 [collection-per-class, parallel (8 threads)]" test-framework="xUnit.net 2.1.0.3179" run-date="2016-02-29" run-time="10:17:15" config-file="xyz" total="4" passed="2" failed="0" skipped="2" time="46.081" errors="0">
    <errors />
    <collection total="4" passed="2" failed="0" skipped="2" name="xyz" time="45.641">
      <test name="CashFactorSetInValidValues" type="XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGuiGeneral" method="CashFactorSetInValidValues" time="22.7359448" result="Pass">
        <traits>
          <trait name="DataManager" value="General" />
          <trait name="General" value="CashFactor" />
        </traits>
      </test>
      <test name="TestCurrencySetAll" type="XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGuiGeneral" method="TestCurrencySetAll" time="0" result="Skip">
        <traits>
          <trait name="DataManager" value="General" />
          <trait name="General" value="Currency" />
        </traits>
        <reason><![CDATA[Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "Xunit.SkipException" wurde ausgelöst.]]></reason>
      </test>
      <test name="TestCurrencyAllAvailable" type="XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGuiGeneral" method="TestCurrencyAllAvailable" time="0" result="Skip">
        <traits>
          <trait name="DataManager" value="General" />
          <trait name="General" value="Currency" />
        </traits>
        <reason><![CDATA[Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "Xunit.SkipException" wurde ausgelöst.]]></reason>
      </test>
      <test name="CashfactorSetValidValues" type="XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGuiGeneral" method="CashfactorSetValidValues" time="14.8607297" result="Pass">
        <traits>
          <trait name="DataManager" value="General" />
          <trait name="General" value="CashFactor" />
        </traits>
      </test>
    </collection>
  </assembly>
</assemblies>
```

I am using the new XUnit Function [SkippableFact] and 2 of the Tests I skipped. The Result.xml is ok and shows exactly what happened, but it can't be interpreted as it seems.

EDIT: I tested it without the SkippableFact and it still doesn't work.